# margin-top behavior differs between browsers

Tags: html, css, firefox, user-interface, google-chrome

We have a richfaces table (rich-table style class) and we would like to have some space on top of the table. We tried using margin-top on the above style class with values in px and in %age. But the resultant behavior was different in both the browsers. FF produces more space compared to Chrome. How do we get around this issue and be browser agnostic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to consider using a [reset stylesheet](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/).

> A reset stylesheet will reduce browser inconsistencies like default line heights, margins and font sizes of headings.

You may also want to check the following articles for further reading on the topic:

- [CSS Tip #1: Resetting Your Styles with CSS Reset](http://sixrevisions.com/css/css-tips/css-tip-1-resetting-your-styles-with-css-reset/)
- [Mayerweb: Reset Reasoning](http://meyerweb.com/eric/thoughts/2007/04/18/reset-reasoning/)
- [Stack Overflow: Is it ok to use a css reset stylesheet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/167531/is-it-ok-to-use-a-css-reset-stylesheet)
- [Stack Overflow: Best css reset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/116754/best-css-reset/116793)